# How to store generic JSON in MongoDB?

Tags: json, mongodb, morphia

Is there a proper way to store generic JSON in MongoDB?  With 'generic' I mean any JSON, including hashes with [keys that are restricted in MongoDB documents](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#field-names).

For example, we want to store JSON schemas which use the key `$ref`, which is not allowed in a MongoDB document.  This means that a JSON schema as such cannot be stored as a MongoDB document.

Is there a smart way around this?  The only options I've come up with is to do back-and-forth deep key replacements or to store it as JSON text.

We're using Morphia, so the solution should be compatible with it.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions you have already thought of are probably the best.  Store the schemas as JSON strings then parse them back to JSON on retrieval.